# How to print an item from the list using Python?

Tags: python, list

can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?!!

```
def make_list(number):
      names =[]
      for item in range(0,number):
          names.append(input("Enter your name"))
      print(names)
       
number = int(input("How many names need to be entered?"))
names = make_list(number)
for name in names:
    if name[0] == "A":
        print("Name", name)
```

Comment: Please don't change OP's original code @Sujay. Ask them what they intended in the comments.

Comment: Function make_list should return names.  Otherwise, names = make_list(number) will set names to None.

Comment: The bottom part of the question was inside the function, where the function was called, and the inside loop ran in the number parameter which was provided inside the function. So I moved it out.@Vishnudev

Comment: What if the OP has it inside the function? @Sujay. Just saying, ask before changing.

Answer (score 1):

In `make_list`, you're printing `names`, then implicitly returning `None`.  Change the `print` to a `return`:

```
def make_list(number):
    names =[]
    for item in range(0,number):
        names.append(input("Enter your name with a capital letter."))
    return names
```

This way the caller will assign the list to `names` rather than `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than printing the name in the function, the fix is to return the names array.

```
def make_list(number):
      names =[]
      for item in range(0,number):
          names.append(input("Enter your name with a capital letter. "))
      return (names)
       
number = int(input("How many names need to be entered? "))
names = make_list(number)
for name in names:
    if name[0] == "A":
        print("Name", name, "starts with A")
```

Sample Output:

```
How many names need to be entered? 2
Enter your name with a capital letter. Andrew
Enter your name with a capital letter. Abby
Name Andrew starts with A
Name Abby starts with A
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to return the value from the function make_list to names in the main code

```
def make_list(number):
  names =[]
  for item in range(0,number):
      names.append(input("Enter your name with a capital letter."))
  print(names)
  return names
   
number = int(input("How many names need to be entered?"))
names = make_list(number)
for name in names:
    if name[0] == "A":
       print("Name", name, "starts with A")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_list(number):
    names =[]
    for item in range(0,number):
        names.append(input("Enter your name with a capital letter. "))
    return (names)
   
number = int(input("How many names need to be entered? "))
names = make_list(number)
for name in names:
    print(f"Name {name} starts with {name[0]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, `number=int(input("blah")) ...` was inside the function `make_list()` so `make_list()` never got called. Additionally, you need to `return names` at the end of `make_list()`, otherwise it implicitly returns `None`, the return value of `print()`.